# How to convert Maven project to normal java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I am trying to convert Docx file to pdf file java using apache poi, itext, Xdocreport but its working on maven project using pom file. we don't need a maven project, so I disabled maven nature in eclipse in maven but still its always showing different dependencies. how to make it work after deconverting maven to java project?

Comment: This is an unusual request. If you don't use Maven, you need to define all dependencies (with all transitive dependencies) in the `.classpath` in Eclipse. Furthermore, you can only build the project in Eclipse then, not on your build server. On the other hand, I don't see any advantage in _not_ using Maven.

Comment: I extracted all the jar files in maven and I added to referenced library after disabled maven nature but still, it's not working.

Comment: Why not using Maven...Makes life easier..but of course it's your turn...

Comment: Is there any constraint for not using maven, or any dependency mgt?

Comment: Maven does a lot of things automatically.  If you disable those, you have to do them by hand.  This is usually a quite menial task which is why Maven was introduced in the first place.

Comment: but in our os we are not going to use maven project, so looking for manual method

Comment: What do you mean by "in our os we are not going to use maven project"? Just to make sure you know that: Maven is _not_ needed to run the project that you build, so your customers do _not_ need Maven.

Comment: I think you have a XY problem see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. You are asking a complicated solution, but your problem is how to use maven in your case.

Comment: we developing our own operating system, so our company not recommending to use maven. we are tring to convert docx to pdf file in java. In maven project, its working but iam adding the same jar file in normal java project, it not working.so i want o know the differences in maven and java project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happy to see someone needs that feature I implemented all those years ago in [JBoss Tools](https://tools.jboss.org/downloads/) :-) I'll basically copy/paste the content of what I wrote in  https://docs.jboss.org/tools/whatsnew/core/core-news-3.3.0.M4.html back then:

Basically, after installing the JBoss Tools JDT Extensions feature, you can right-click on a Classpath Library from one of your Java projects (In the Project Explorer view for example, go under Java Resources > Libraries) and select the "Materialize Library..." menu.
[image: Materialize Library menu]

This will open a new dialog window in which you can choose the destination folder into which will be copied the selected jars:

[image: Materialize Library wizard]

Once materialized, jars are copied and referenced directly in the classpath, the Classpath Library is removed. in the case of Maven-powered projects, the Maven nature is removed, thus disabling the Maven builder. If you want to enable the Maven nature back on, just right-click on your project and select `Configure > Convert to Maven Project`.

Answer (score 1):

Maven pulled all required jars into the local repository.

After you removed the pom.xml and modified the `.project` file that it does not contain any more Maven reference (basically the <nature> and the <buildCommand>), you create a new folder `lib` in the root of your project and copy all the jars from the local Maven repository to that new folder.

Then add the jars to the CLASSPATH ('Properties'|'Java Build Path', and there 'Libraries'). If configured, the local Maven repository holds also the JavaDoc and the Source jars; these need not to be added to the CLASSPATH, for obvious reasons, but you should add a reference to them to the respective binary jars.